# How to have prod and dev ENV in symfony4 at the same time

Tags: symfony, environment, symfony4

Before Symfony4 you have 2 files for environments app.php and app_dev.php that give us the possibility to change in environment quickly only with the url.

I miss this feature in my actual production site.

There is a way to have both at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution and works for me

I don't know if it is the right way.

```
//public/index.php
<?php
# To force to dev environment when the cookies exist
if (isset($_COOKIE['somekey'])) {
   $env = 'dev';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just duplicate your index.php and modify it to force it as dev environment

Comment: I've tried this, but it does not work. Could you edit the answer with a piece of code please?. My versions are: symfony 4.0.8 php 7.2.4 apache 2.4.18

Answer (score 0):

You can just duplicate your index.php as index_dev.php and modify where it instantiate your Kernel class.

```
//index_dev.php
$env = 'dev'; // or you can use any other environment names here
$kernel = new Kernel($env, $debug);
```